# Send to OneNote in Office 2016?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office

In previous versions of OneNote I could press <kbd>OS Key</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the *Send to OneNote* dialog.  From this dialog I could do several things, including take a screen clipping and save it to the clipboard.

However, in Office 2016 this keyboard shortcut no longer does anything and I can't find anything called "Send to OneNote".  Has Microsoft removed this feature in 2016?  If not where can I find it, if so, why, and is there a replacement feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Office 2016, "Send to OneNote" ran as a separate exe with its own window.  In 2016 it is a windowless exe that runs in the system tray (the place on the desktop with all the icons, next to the clock).  This should be running by default, you can check your system tray:

[image]

If you don't see it, open OneNote and navigate to File >> Options and select "Display" and make sure "Place OneNote icon in the notification area of the taskbar" is checked:

[image]

To configure where stuff goes when sent to OneNote, go to the "Send to OneNote" tab:

[image]

If you right click on the tray icon, it will bring up the keyboard shortcuts available:

[image]

The thing that's missing from previous versions of the app is the button that would "Send to OneNote" from various apps (IE, Word, etc).  Apparently this is now the responsibility of the other applications instead of being controlled through the "Send to OneNote" tool (i.e. you need to click the appropriate "Send to OneNote" button in the other apps).

Here is a ["User Voice" suggestion](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/327186-onenote-for-windows-windows-phone/suggestions/10174485-send-to-onenote-tool-function)  to bring back the previous incarnation of "Send to OneNote"

Comment: It seems that this tray icon (and its functionalities) do not appear until I have opened OneNote.  Can I get it to show all the time?  (To clarify: I can open OneNote *and then immediately close it*, and the tray icon will still be present, but it won't appear until OneNote has been opened since I have been signed in.)

Answer (score 0):

Find it in location:
OneNote--> File--> Options --> Display --> check "Dock new Quick Note windows..."

[image: configuration panel]